# The derivative of $ 2^{\frac{x}{\ln x}} $

Tags: derivatives

I am supposed to find the derivative of $ 2^{\frac{x}{\ln x}} $. My answer is $$ 2^{\frac{x}{\ln x}} \cdot \ln 2 \cdot  \frac{\ln x-x\cdot \frac{1}{x}}{\ln^{2}x}\cdot \frac{1}{x} .$$ Is it correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct. You  have just an **extra** factor $1/x$ at the end. The correct derivative is
$$D(2^{\frac{x}{\ln x}})=2^{\frac{x}{\ln x}} \cdot  \ln 2 \cdot D\left(\frac{x}{\ln x}\right)=2^{\frac{x}{\ln x}} \cdot  \ln 2 \cdot \frac{\ln x-x\cdot \frac{1}{x}}{\ln^{2}x}.$$

Comment: Isn't your answer the same as mine?

Comment: Your answer had an extra $\frac{1}{x}$ at the end.

Comment: No, you have en extra factor $1/x$ ate the end.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=2^\frac{x}{\ln{x}}$.  Then

$$\ln{y}=\ln{2}^{\frac{x}{\ln{x}}}=\frac{x}{\ln{x}}\cdot\ln2$$

Now $$\frac{1}{y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=\ln{2}\left[\frac{\ln{x}-1}{(\ln x)^2}\right]$$

Now multiply by $y$ and get

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\ln{2}\left[\frac{\ln{x}-1}{(\ln x)^2}\right]=2^\frac{x}{\ln{x}}\ln{2}\left[\frac{\ln{x}-1}{(\ln x)^2}\right]$$

You can do all sorts of algebra to reduce this but it is the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* gives:

$$\frac{\log (2) 2^{\frac{x}{\log (x)}} (\log (x)-1)}{\log ^2(x)}$$

Comment: But that is after simplification, right? Mine is without.

Comment: Did you press the right buttons? Your derivative seems to be wrong!

Comment: Oopsss... fixed.  Thanks.